# constructor definition within a method call

Tags: java, constructor

So i was following this tutorial, and found something i find confusing.

```
ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
        @Override
        public InputStream open() throws IOException {
            return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
        }
    });
```

Now i dont consider myself a java expert or anything, but I'm not a complete newbie either, and i hadn't ever seen this kind of thing, meaning a constructor definition on a call. That doesnt look like java at all, at least to me. The question is, does that particular way of defining a constructor on the fly have a name so i can learn more about it, because i'm quite confused to be honest.

Comment: There are many questions about this, it's called an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5).

Comment: yes, google around anonymous classes. you will find plenty of material

Answer (score 5):

It's an [anonymous class constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1) for an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5), which is a shorthand way of creating a subclass. [Here's the Oracle tutorial on anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).